# Float value conversion in the database

Tags: mysql, floating-point, rounding, type-conversion

In my database some fields (amount, balance) are assigned as floating value, but now i have a problem with that .if the amount is 1.56 it will take 1.6
then i alter the table using Round(amount,2)
still it shows the same problem.
if anybody know please help me.

Comment: If you working with currency, better use Decimal data type. You can change your column data type to `Decimal(18, 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The float fields must be declared as float(some_integer, 1) to show the behaviour you described. The first integer in such a declaration tells MySQL how much digits should be visible alltogether, the ones left to the decimal point **+** the ones right to it. To have 3 digits to the left and 2 to the right of the decimal point you would declare it as `float(5,2)`.

Like Doan Cuong already mentioned it would be better if you would choose decimal data type.

See the different behaviour of it [live here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13f73/1/0).

To quote the manual:

> The DECIMAL and NUMERIC types store exact numeric data values. These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, for example with monetary data.
>
> The FLOAT and DOUBLE types represent approximate numeric data values.

For additional info about the data types read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html).